# Sprite sheet scheme for a three-style grid in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I am working in some game idea with Android and AndEngine, but I can't find a good tiling approach.

Some part of the game will consist on a rectangular grid. Three "styles" are possible, for each square side of the grid or the inner square. For simplicity we can think about gray, blue and red.

The problem is, when I think about making the sprite sheet, I'm not sure how to do it.

This is a quick (and bad drawing) of my first thoughts, being black the grid and green the cuts. Problem with this one is I would need to have up to **512** versions of the line crossing.

[image: Bad drawing]

Is there a better approach? Can I do that without sprite sheets, just drawing lines and filling rectangles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I can't follow your thoughts completely. But, I understand you are handling a lot of squares and lines in different styles. And that's where you are right, you don't need any `Sprites` for that, `AndEngine` has some classes to draw simple things and it is way faster than Sprites.

**basic example that reproduces your graphic with lines**

```
// first the green lines (they are under the black ones)
Line[] greenLines = new Line[8];
 // from (x0 ,y0) to (x1,y1) with lineWidth=5px
 // the outer square
greenLines[0] = new Line(0, 0, 100, 0, 5, vertexBufferObjectManager);  // top line
greenLines[1] = new Line(100, 0, 100, 100, 5, vertexBufferObjectManager); // right line
greenLines[2] = new Line(100, 100, 0, 100, 5, vertexBufferObjectManager); // bottom line
greenLines[3] = new Line(0, 100, 0, 0, 5, vertexBufferObjectManager);  // left line

 // inner horizontal lines
greenLines[4] = new Line(0, 33, 100, 33, 5, vertexBufferObjectManager);  
greenLines[5] = new Line(0, 66, 100, 66, 5, vertexBufferObjectManager);
 // inner vertical lines
greenLines[6] = new Line(33, 0, 33, 100, 5, vertexBufferObjectManager);  
greenLines[7] = new Line(66, 0, 66, 100, 5, vertexBufferObjectManager);

// now the black lines
 Line[] blackLines = new Line[4];
blackLines[0] = new Line(0, 15, 100, 15, 5, vertexBufferObjectManager);
blackLines[1] = new Line(0, 81, 100, 81, 5, vertexBufferObjectManager);
blackLines[2] = new Line(15, 0, 15, 100, 5, vertexBufferObjectManager);
blackLines[3] = new Line(81, 0, 81, 100, 5, vertexBufferObjectManager);

// now set the color and attach the lines to the scene (green)
for(Line line: greenLines){
    line.setColor(0f,1f,0f);
    myScene.attachChild(line);
}

// now set the color and attach the lines to the scene (black)
for(Line line: blackLines){
    line.setColor(0f,0f,0f);
    myScene.attachChild(line);
}
```

this above example should actually work. Now you only have to change it and adjust it to your needs. If you want to change a line you could call `myLine.setPosition(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);` oh and a rectangle is quite simple as well: `Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(50,50,100,100, 5, vertexBufferObjectManager);` for a rectangle that starts at (50,50) and is 100 pixels wide and 100 pixels high. And has a line width of 5 pixels. You can set the color of the Rectangle as you can for the lines. The only *problem* is, that the rectangle is always filled. If you want an empty rectangle you have to draw it with lines.

Answer (score -2):

```
public Line buildGrid(int pWidth, int pHeight, float pRed, float pGreen, float pBlue){
    Line grid = new Line(0, 0, 0, pHeight);
    grid.setColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    int cont = 0;

    while(cont < pWidth){
            cont += 10;
            grid.attachChild(new Line(cont, 0, cont, pHeight));
            grid.getLastChild().setColor(pRed, pGreen, pBlue);                     
    }

    cont = 0;
    while (cont < pHeight){
            cont += 10;
            grid.attachChild(new Line(0, cont, pWidth, cont));
            grid.getLastChild().setColor(pRed, pGreen, pBlue);
    }

    return grid;
}
```